# create square in matlab on white canvas given center coordinates

Tags: matlab, square

I'm very new to Matlab. I need to create squares on white canvases based off specs given to me in a file squares.txt. The text document contains a matrix of numbers with 6 columns and some rows. The first two numbers in each row of the matrix are the center coordinates of the square to be drawn. The third value is the width, and the last values are RGB values. I'm having a very difficult time finding a way to draw a square on a canvas given the center coordinates.

Comment: Is the `rectangle` function defined by you, or are you trying to use the Matlab function, which would look something like: `rectangle('Position',[x,y,w,h])`?

Comment: I'm trying to use the Matlab function

Comment: drawing a rectangle would then look like: `sq = rectangle('Position', [i-width/2, j-width/2,  width, width]);`

Comment: Thanks, can you give me any pointers on setting the color of the square using RGB values?

Comment: sure, I have now made a proper answer out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing a colored square, given the centre coordinates, the width and the RGB values, looks like:

```
sq = rectangle('Position', [i-width/2, j-width/2, width, width],'EdgeColor',[r g b]);
```

depending on whether your color values are between 0 and 1 or 0 and 255 you may have to divide `r`, `g` and `b` by 255

**Edit:**

Minimal example without using the file:

```
width=100;
for count = 1:2
    if (count == 1)
       canvas = ones(400,400,3);
    else
        canvas = ones(300,700,3);
    end
    figure, imshow (canvas);
    rectangle('Position', [100-width/2, 200-width/2,  width, width], 
EdgeColor', [0.5 0.5 0.2]);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited the code to show what I have currently. Unfortunately, it's still not working as intended. Firstly, it's not drawing multiple boxes on each canvas and secondly, after one box is drawn on the first canvas an error occurs in my draw_box function. Can you spot what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if I made this clear but it should first draw all of the squares on a 400x400 canvas and then draw all the squares on a 300x700 canvas so that the result is two images of white canvases with squares.

Comment: @SamiBoleyn What does the error say? Also, I would suggest to take `figure, imshow(canvas)` out of the `draw_box` function, since you don't want a new figure to be opened every time

Comment: I took your advice on removing figure, imshow(canvas) and I no longer get the error. The program is almost where it should be. Instead of creating two figures, it just creates the first figure (with the 400x400 canvas). Ideas?

Comment: @SamiBoleyn That's strange. To me it seems ok now. The minimal example, which I have put into the answer now opens two figures with different canvases and draws a square in both of them. Do you see any difference to your program?

Comment: The minimalist code you provided does open up two figures and draws squares in both of them. I'm still struggling with how to apply these fixes to my code though.

Comment: I believe I have it figured out, thanks to your help! I edited the code to show my final answer. It appears I needed to add a figure, imshow(canvass) when I create the new_img. Regards.

Comment: @SamiBoleyn Perfect! Glad I could help.